# How to save Web page complate in MVC (Webpage,complete(*.htm;,html))

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How can we programatically save complete web page in MVC?

I mean I want to save page as " Webpage,complete(*.htm;,*html)" style. I used the WebClient but it save only the HTML page. I awnt both page as well as images etc.. like saving webpage CTRL + s as Complete webpage. Please share if anyone knows

Regards
Sreyas MN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# code for saving an entire web page? (with images/formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430918/c-sharp-code-for-saving-an-entire-web-page-with-images-formatting)

Comment: I want it to Web. I mean MVC.Webbrowser works in windows app